# drag and drop : forcing a dragged shadow to not go back to the initial position

Tags: java, android, drag-and-drop, android-animation

i have a constraint layout with flow to make a multi line chain of unknow number of different size textviews , my current goal is to implement a drag and drop funtionality to this layout which will make it possible for the user to play with the order of the elements of the flow by dragging them around (such functionality can be found in the implementation of drag and drop of recyclervire class)

the problem : after dragging the shadow around my code is changing the position of the original textview (which the shadow represent) and everything works fine , however when the user drops the shadow , the shadow animates to the original position of the textview which no longer is there (it transfered visualy to anither position) , i want the shadow to just disappear when its dropped instead of animated back to its original position .

here is my java code :

```
    public void onImageClick(View view){
        draggedTextView = null ; //this variable is global and used to store the current dragged textview
        ArrayList<TextView> textViews = new ArrayList<>() ;

        //the dialog is used to open a new layout upon the mainLayout and its the problem accrues here 
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this) ;
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.transparent);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.menu_for_collaping_tool_bar);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        Button btn = dialog.findViewById(R.id.appCompatButton) ;
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        //the layout which contains the flow
        ConstraintLayout interestsLayout = dialog.findViewById(R.id.constraintLayout2) ;
        Flow interestsLayoutFlow = dialog.findViewById(R.id.flow) ;

        //this two variables and the first for loop is for creating the default state of the flow
        //in addition to adding the data to the flow represented with textViews
        int lastRandom = -1 ;
        int currRandom = -1 ;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < interestsArray.size() ; i ++){
            TextView textView = new TextView(this) ;
            textView.setId(View.generateViewId());
            textView.setText(interestsArray.get(i));
            textView.setGravity(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
            textView.setPadding(20,20,20,20);
            textView.setLayoutParams(new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT , ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            do{
                lastRandom = currRandom ;
                currRandom = (int)(Math.random()*5) + 1 ;
            }while (lastRandom == currRandom) ;
            assignBorder(textView , currRandom);

            interestsLayout.addView(textView);
            interestsLayoutFlow.addView(textView);

            textViews.add(textView) ;

            //i have no idea what the hell is that
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                textView.updateDragShadow(new View.DragShadowBuilder(textView));
            }
        }
        
        //this for loop is where the listeners and the drag and drop functionality is being defined
        for (TextView textView : textViews) {
            textView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                    System.out.println(textView);
                    String str = textView.getId() + "";
                    ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item((CharSequence) str);
                    ClipData dragData = new ClipData("data",
                            new String[]{ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN}, item);
                    View.DragShadowBuilder dragShadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(textView);
                    int[] arr = interestsLayoutFlow.getReferencedIds() ;
                    textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    textView.setEnabled(false);

                    interestsLayoutFlow.setReferencedIds(arr);
                    interestsLayoutFlow.setWrapMode(Flow.WRAP_CHAIN);
                    draggedTextView = textView ;

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                        // (1) The data to be dragged.
                        // (2) The drag shadow builder.
                        // (3) No need to use local data.
                        // (4) Flags. Not currently used, set to 0.
                        textView.startDragAndDrop(dragData, dragShadowBuilder, null, 0);
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
            textView.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onDrag(View view, DragEvent dragEvent) {
                    switch (dragEvent.getAction()) {
                        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                            if (dragEvent.getClipDescription().hasMimeType(ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN)) {
                                return true;
                            }
                            return false;
                        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                            int[] arr1 = interestsLayoutFlow.getReferencedIds();
                            int textIndex = -1 ;
                            int viewIndex = -1 ;
                            for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
                                if(arr1[i] == view.getId())
                                    viewIndex = i ;
                                if (arr1[i] == draggedTextView.getId())
                                    textIndex = i ;
                            }
                            int tmp = arr1[viewIndex] ;
                            arr1[viewIndex] = arr1[textIndex] ;
                            arr1[textIndex] = tmp ;

                            interestsLayoutFlow.setReferencedIds(arr1);
                            interestsLayoutFlow.setWrapMode(Flow.WRAP_CHAIN);
                            return true;

                        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
                            return true;

                        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                            return true;

                        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                            return true;

                        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                            //TODO: if the shadow wasn't dropped at any view then make it go back to its starting position
                            int[] arr3 = interestsLayoutFlow.getReferencedIds();
                            draggedTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            draggedTextView.setEnabled(true);

                            interestsLayoutFlow.setReferencedIds(arr3);
                            interestsLayoutFlow.setWrapMode(Flow.WRAP_CHAIN);
                            return true;

                        default:
                            throw new IllegalArgumentException("hello");
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        dialog.show();
    }
```

and this is the xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp">
    <!--    TODO:remove the 400dp and make it a match constraint somehow-->

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#ff666666"
        app:cardCornerRadius="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout8"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                        android:id="@+id/appCompatButton"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/black_close_icon"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/img"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1000dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="50dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout8"
                    app:layout_constraintWidth="match_constraint">

                    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                            android:id="@+id/first_layout"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:padding="10dp"
                            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                            <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
                                android:id="@+id/image"
                                android:layout_width="75dp"
                                android:layout_height="75dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/img_1"
                                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/nameTV"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textSize="18dp"
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                android:text="mohammad alatawna"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/image"
                                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:text="mohammadalatawna111@gmail.com"
                                android:textSize="13dp"
                                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/nameTV"
                                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/nameTV" />

                            <ImageButton
                                android:layout_width="40dp"
                                android:layout_height="40dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                android:background="@color/transparent"
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_arrow_circle_down_24"
                                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/image"
                                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textView5"
                                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/image" />


                            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                                android:layout_width="150dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="button"
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/image"/>

                        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

                        <View
                            android:id="@+id/line1"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="3dp"
                            android:background="#66000000"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/first_layout"/>

                        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout2"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/line1"
                            android:padding="10dp"
                            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

                            <androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow
                                android:id="@+id/flow"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                app:layout_constraintWidth="match_constraint"
                                app:flow_horizontalGap="5dp"
                                app:flow_horizontalStyle="packed"
                                app:flow_horizontalBias="1"
                                app:flow_verticalGap="10dp"
                                app:flow_wrapMode="chain"
                                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
                        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                            android:id="@+id/editInterestsButton"
                            android:layout_width="200dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="edit interests"
                            android:background="@drawable/rounded_rectangle"
                            android:backgroundTint="@color/teal_200"
                            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/constraintLayout2"/>
                        <View
                            android:id="@+id/line2"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="3dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                            android:background="#66000000"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editInterestsButton"/>
                    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </ScrollView>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```